# Jsf and tomahawk dataScroller sorting and pagination issue

Tags: jsf-2.2, tomahawk

My application is using jsf 2.4.0 and tomahawk1.1.11. I am facing exception compatability issues with dataScroller(sorting groups and pagination) not working.

Can anyone suggest me which is jsf 2.4.0 compatible tomahawk version and any alternative to dataScroller.

Thanks

Comment: please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. There is no real jsf 2.4.0

Comment: And there is a tomahawk2.1-1.1.14, tried that?